# How to print latest commit id of kernel code in kernel log?

Tags: c, linux, git, linux-kernel

For some debug purpose i need to print the latest commit id of linux kernel's source code in kernel log. So how to do that?

I know latest commit id can be known by `git rev-parse HEAD` but how to print its o/p in linux kernel log.

Is there any way so i can invoke any command like `system("git rev-parse HEAD")`in linux kernel code and store its o/p in string or in macro. This should be done at **compilation time** and at **run time** need to print that string or macro's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build upon the answer from abeaumet, I recommend something like this:

```
gcc main.c -DKERNEL_LAST_COMMIT="\"$(cd /kernel/source/path ; git rev-parse HEAD)\""
```

Comment: I think you can avoid the `\"` cause the sub-shell output is already quoted.

Comment: @abeaumet Not really, since the hash looks something like `78d64ccefd7713b4af07b9f05f5060e1612ecfa9` which needs to be a string in the code.

Comment: Hum yes I didn't consider that problem. I deleted my response as yours seems simply correct :)

Comment: on CLI it works fine...even with "\"hello\"" works from kernel make file but when i try with $(command) it does not work from make file

Comment: @Mr.32 In a `Makefile` the dollar sign is special, you might want to either double it (i.e. `$$(...)`) or use backticks (i.e. `\`...\``).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks $$ worked...i just googled and find out that even  $(shell command) also works